# VLC 3.0 (Vetinari): Unable to play 360 videos

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc, 360video, vimeo

I installed the last VLC version (3.0.0 (Vetinari) on Windows 7 64 bits) which supports 360 video playback.

In order to do some tests I downloaded the following 360 video from Vimeo:
https://vimeo.com/215984568

But VLC is unable to play the 360 video correctly; the video contains all the 360 degree video information but it's showed at the same time (on Vimeo the video plays OK). The result is the following:
[image]

I think that maybe the video could be reencoded with ffmpeg to be more VLC friendly.

The media info of the downloaded 360 video is this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 360° video you downloaded is encoded as an equirectangular projection, meaning the video was projected onto a rectangular surface. This makes the video indistinguishable from a normal video.

In order to be recognized as a 360° video, the video must contain specific metadata. You can use a tool provided by Google for uploading videos to YouTube: [Upload 360-degree videos](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6178631?hl=en). Apply this tool to your video and VLC will correctly recognize it as a 360° video.

Comment: Thanks Manuel. VLC recognized the video as a 360° video.

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from the video which should have the metadata `projection=equirectangular`. To fix it:

1. Install [Python 3](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/python-3.7.3.exe)
2. Download [Spatial Media](https://github.com/tongwenchao/spatial-media/archive/refs/heads/master.zip)
3. Unzip Spatial Media
4. Go into the folder (where there is a subfolder `spatialmedia`)
5. Copy the path of the folder
6. Launch `cmd` on Windows (by searching `cmd` on your system)
7. Go on the folder by typing `cd`  and the path of the folder
8. Inject the spherical metadata by typing `py spatialmedia -i` **`<yourVideoOnTheDisk>`** **`<aVideoName>`**

Open the created file with VLC. It should be launched as a 360° video. You can remove `spatialmedia` and uninstall Python.

Comment: This methode might work, VLC can't read stereoscopic tom-bottom and i don't think there is any windows player that would allow read a 4096x4096 top bottom video for inspection.